# How to visualize the size of a word depending on its value

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, data-visualization, word-cloud

I don't know if this is possible, or how to even approach this, but is there a way to do the follow?

I have a df that looks like this:

```
          0                                1
5  0.968470                              car
0  0.014322                            adult
4  0.013177                            child
6  0.001174                          mailbox
7  0.001163                        lightpost
1  0.001144                          bicycle
3  0.000200                         stopsign
2  0.000184                     trafficlight
8  0.000165                              dog
```

It is the probability distribution output of a classification problem. I want to print out the words (column[0]), but have the font size reflect the probability value (column[1[) for that row. Kind of like a word cloud, which prints words in bigger font when they have higher frequency.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Where would the font size print out? Do you want this in a word cloud?

Comment: Yea, something like that. I just want to write some code to print it out in the terminal or a notebook, using something like matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wordcloud has an option [`generate_from_frequencies`](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html?highlight=generate_from_frequencies) which uses a dictionary with relative frequencies. The parameter `prefer_horizontal=1` can be used to force only horizontal words (default is `0.9`: about 10% vertical words).

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

d = {w: f for w, f in
     zip(['car', 'adult', 'child', 'mailbox', 'lightpost', 'bicycle', 'stopsign', 'trafficlight', 'dog'],
         [0.968470, 0.014322, 0.013177, 0.001174, 0.001163, 0.001144, 0.000200, 0.000184, 0.000165])}
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color='turquoise', colormap='inferno', prefer_horizontal=1)
wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies=d)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting wordcloud]